# First Image Change not Fading In or Out

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using this function to swap through images,
but when it swaps for the first time it doesn't fade in or out they just swap instantly. Then after the first instant swap it works perfectly does anyone know why this would be?

```
function swapImages(){
  var $active = $('#maincontent .current01');
  var $next = ($('#maincontent .current01').next().length > 0) ? $('#maincontent .current01').next() : $('#maincontent img:first');
  $next.addClass('next01');
  $active.fadeOut(3000)
    $next.fadeIn(3000,function(){
    $active.removeClass('current01');
    $next.removeClass('next01');
    $next.addClass('current01');
    setTimeout ('swapImages()', 7000);
  });
}

// Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
setTimeout('swapImages()', 6000);
```

Cheers, A.D

Answer (score 1):

If youre using jQuery i would just use [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). Its perfect for this.